# Can I save memory by reducing image size?

Tags: objective-c, image, memory

i've a lot of images as background and other decorations.

If i reduce their resolution and their size, the memory used by all application will be reduced or will i not have advantages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the file is reduced it will use less memory. 1 thing you could do is using sprites instead of images, though using a sprite in objective-c is a bit more difficult than it is on the web.

You could also try to replace images with custom drawing code in subclasses of views.

Comment: +1 for drawing in code, that’s a good idea (if it’s possible).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you reduce image resolution, there will be less data to keep in memory and total memory usage will go down. But remember the basic rule of optimization and *measure first*, so that you know for sure that reducing image size will really make a difference given the rest of your application. (As an example, if you have serious leaks in your application, there’s not much to be gained by resampling images.)